# Error while copying from network share "This page has an unspecified potential security flaw."

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I recently reinstalled XP and then SP3 and I'm currently getting an error whenever I try and copy something from a network share.

```
Title: Internet Explorer
Message: This page has an unspecified potential security flaw.
         Would you like to continue?
```

I believe it's related to [KB921398 (MS06-045)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/921398) and I'm currently uninstalling SP3, but does anyone know if there is another way to disable this specific update? It does not appear in Add & Remove Programs.

There's a temporary fix by adding any network ip masks to the trusted intranet zones in Internet Explorer's Security settings, but it's no fix :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There's a temporary fix by adding any network ip masks to the trusted intranet zones

That's the real fix. The error message occurs when you are trying to copy files out of the Internet Zone. And it is indeed risky if you really are dragging files out of a public-internet network share, so the message isn't really wrong (just vague and misleading).

To avoid the error popping up in your intranet — and because it's the right thing to do anyway — you need to make sure Windows sees the intranet as being in the Local intranet Zone.

Go to Control Panel -> Internet Options-> Security -> Local intranet -> Sites. If “Automatically detect intanet network” is ticked, untick it as obviously the automatic detection isn't working. Turn on the top two; if you're sure that you will never be accessing network shares outside the intranet (eg. because a firewall prevents it), you can tick “Include all network paths”.

If this doesn't work add the folder path as a trusted Local Intranet site.

Comment: It's a shame, I'd like something a little more concrete :(, but thanks all the same.

Comment: adding all unc paths worked for me. why should internet explorer be so tied up with the file explorer beats me...

Comment: Why is dragging a file out of a public-internet network share riskier than, for example, simply downloading a file from a public-internet website?

Comment: Because a file on the filesystem can be an executable—maybe dressed up not to look like one—or a file with scripting abilities. When you download a file from a web site with IE, it'll receive a zone identifier ADS to warn you before opening it; but I don't think this works with file copying from a UNC. Perhaps it should.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct fix, because of the tie in between IE and Windows Explorer. What i have found is a neat trick because all of our servers export their windows shares on a common subnet. add this one line to Intranet Setting "File://192.168.0.*" (change for your correct subnet).